# How to change color and stroke of one type of edges

Tags: java, jung, transformer-model, jung2

I have a Graph< Potter, Edge> g where Edges belongs to three different classes that extends the Edge class (I use it to represent different type of interactions, like begin related, ask advices and so on...). I would like to color edges accordingly to what they represent, like having all Parental edges turn green and not display arrows. I have this transformer to change color, but it appears to change colors to all the edges:

```
Transformer<Edge, Paint> parental_color_yes = new Transformer<Edge, Paint>() {
        @Override
        public Paint transform(Edge s) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        }
    };
```

If I change the type of the transformer to Transformer< Parental, Paint>, then my VisualizationViewer< Potter, Edge> vv complains that cannot accept such a transformer... should I add a new visualization viewer? or there is something wrong in the transformer?

EDITED after the reply:

```
 parental_color_yes = new Transformer<Edge, Paint>() {
        @Override
        public Paint transform(Edge s) {
            if (s instanceof Parental){
                return Color.GREEN;
            } else if (s instanceof Innovation) {
                return Color.RED;
            } else {
                return Color.BLACK;
            }
        }
    };
```

Thank you for the help!

Best regards,
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be an Edge-Paint Transformer.  Inside the transform method, use an instanceof check to see what color to return.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the question to add your answer... just a last hint, where should I look to hide the arrows or to color the arrows?

Comment: To color the arrows: setArrow{Draw,Fill}PaintTransformer; to hide them, setEdgeArrowPredicate.  I recommend looking at (Pluggable)RenderContext and the PluggableRenderDemo to get an understanding of the system capabilities and how to use them.